# Cadastrar tipos de usuários diferentes no django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Tenho três tipos de usuários: **Gestor, Professor e Aluno**. Todos eles precisam logar na no sistema, porém o professor e aluno tem algumas informações a mais.
O gestor que cria o acesso do Aluno e Professor. Quero fazer o cadastro pelo Django Admin e quando Clicar para cadastrar o Aluno ou Professor, cadastrar também o User padrão no django na mesma tela.
No Django Admin eu preçiso de três áreas:

- Cadastrar User (padrão)
- Cadastrar Aluno + User
- Cadastrar Professor + User

No modelo padrão ele mostra apenas um select box e um botão de +. Quero o formulário completo na tela.

Segue o código utilizado para criar a classe Aluno

```
class Aluno(models.Model):
    SEXO_CHOICES = ((u'M', 'Masculino'), (u'F', 'Feminino'))

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sexo = models.CharField(choices=SEXO_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    nascimento = models.DateField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

Utilizei o Inline no admin.py para vincular a classe User ao Aluno mas deu erro. Segue o código

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class UserInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = User

class AlunoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (UserInlineAdmin,)
```

Segue o erro apresentado

```
<class 'blog.admin.UserInlineAdmin'>: (admin.E202) 'auth.User' has no ForeignKey to 'blog.Aluno'.
```

Comment: Se eu entendi bem o seu problema, não seria ideal voltar e modelar o seu banco de dados para que as diferenças entre um e outro seja somente uma linha para identificar qual o tipo de usuário? Por exemplo, as classes Aluno, Gestor e Professor herdarem da classe User (que é bem completa).

Comment: De qualquer forma, segue uma resposta no SO com relação ao seu problema e o erro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748059/add-inline-model-to-django-admin-site

Comment: @PauloVinícius Obrigado pela dica. Eu vi essa resposta aí mas aparentemente está igual a minha. O problema é definir essa união com a classe User. Mesmo se remodelar eu ainda preciso de uma área pra cadastrar o Gestor, o colaborador e o Aluno. Só quero cadastrar cada um separado e sem precisar trocar de tela pra cadastrar o User.

Comment: Não sei se faz diferença, mas eles estão usando chaves ao invés de parênteses para atribuir o inlines. Outra coisa, aquela última linha da resposta "admin.site.register(Rule,RuleAdmin)" vai no arquivo admin.py, apesar da pessoa que respondeu não mencionar isso. Mas enfim é só nisso que posso ajudar, não sou um profundo conhecedor de django.

Answer (score 2):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/extend-user2)

Se eu entendi vc não precisa do inline, basta registrar o Aluno e Professor normalmente no admin, veja se é isso:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Aluno(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Adicionando os campos
    matricula = models.CharField('Matrícula', max_length=12)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Professor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Adicionando os campos
    disciplina = models.CharField('Disciplina', max_length=70)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Aluno, Professor

@admin.register(Aluno)
class AlunoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Aluno
    list_display = ('user', 'matricula',)

@admin.register(Professor)
class ProfessorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Professor
    list_display = ('user', 'disciplina',)
```

Sua tela do admin deverá ficar assim:

[image: Tela principal do admin]

A inclusao de um Aluno, por exemplo:

[image: Inclusão de um aluno]

Essas telas capturei repl.it, se vc quiser testar lá, veja o link que deixo abaixo, lembrando que para rodar voce precisa primeiro fazer um fork do projeto, depois, no frame a direita, precisa criar as migrações, fazer o migrate, criar um superuser e finalmente rodar.

### Adicionando `inlines` no `User`:

Com `inlines` vc pode conseguir em uma tela só, em que vc possa fazer a inclusao do `User`, o `Professor` e o `Aluno`, mas na minha opinião, fica um pouco estranho, veja que inlines é para mostrar registro(s) do relacionamento entre uma classe e outra, veja que coloquei no plural, por exemplo quando voce quer mostrar os dados do aluno e suas notas ao longo de um período. O `inline`, por default, vem sempre no plural, nesse caso sua tela de inclusão do `User` ficaria como na figura abaixo (Em seguida adiciono as mudanças no código que vc teria que fazer para isso):

[image: Versão alterando o User no admin]

Eu disse que fica estranho, por quê? Porque `inline` nesse caso vai solicitar os dois relacionamentos, não importa se vc está cadastrando um professor ou um aluno, vai aparecer os campos para a digitacao das duas informações, mas provavelmente um `User` se realcionará a um `Professor` **OU** a um `Aluno`, nunca aos dois simultaneamente, fica estranho.

Note que nesse caso eu apenas re-registrei o `User` no admin, as outras opções continuam como antes, para isso só foi preciso alterar o arquivo `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import Aluno, Professor

class AlunoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Aluno
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name = 'Aluno'

class ProfessorInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Professor
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name = 'Professor'

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (AlunoInline, ProfessorInline)

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

@admin.register(Aluno)
class AlunoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Aluno
    list_display = ('user', 'matricula',)

@admin.register(Professor)
class ProfessorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Professor
    list_display = ('user', 'disciplina',)
```

Se voce quiser evitar o plural no inline (De `Alunos` p/ `Aluno` e/ou `Professores` p/ `Professor`) acrescente nos `models` a classe `Meta`, e altere o `verbose_name_plural`, por exemplo:

```
class Professor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Adicionando os campos
    disciplina = models.CharField('Disciplina', max_length=70)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Professor'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/extend-user2)

Comment: Então, nesse modelo eu preciso abrir outra tela pra poder cadastrar os dados o usuário e selecionar ele no select box. Com o inline ele aparece todos os campos do formulário na tela (o que eu quero).

Comment: Ok, da para fazer com o inline, mas como vc disse que quer uma tela separada para cada `model` eu não consigo vislumbrar como, com o inline da para fazer mas com todos os `models` que estao relacionados com o user na mesma tela (Ou vc teria que registrar o User do django mais de uma vez, n sei se o django permite isso), serve assim?

Comment: Então eu devo ter me expressado errado, desculpa. O que eu preciso é todos os campos na mesma tela sem precisar abrir uma tela diferente, justamente o que o inline oferece. O problema é que não consigo fazer com que os dados do aluno/professor estejam na mesma tela que os dados de acesso do User.

Comment: @FlávioFilipe Editei a resposta, adicionando `inlines` no `User`, veja se é isso.